# Mapping an Array Based on Another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I'm working on a project where I need to change the values of one array should the first index of one of its nested arrays be found within the second array. For example:

**Array One**

```
[12345, [67890, 1], [09876, 2]]
```

**Array Two**

```
[
   [
      180547,
      '180547 text',
      'more text',
      ...etc
   ], [
      67890,
      '67890 text',
      'more text',
      ...etc
   ],
   ...etc
]
```

I need to iterate through each of the nested arrays in `Array One` and check if the first value in each nested array is present in the any of the arrays in `Array Two`. From there, I need to copy `Array Two`'s array, and replace the first value of the nested array in `Array One`.

I know that was probably a little confusing, so here's an example output of the above arrays:

**Output**

```
[12345, [[67890, '67890 text', 'more text', ...etc], 1], [09876, 2]]
```

ES6+ is preferred, but not necessary.

**EDIT:**

As asked for, so given -

Function jargon aside, here's the best I was able to come up with on my own:

```
  gid.steal()
    .then(dataset => {
      let o = dataset.forEach(group => {
        group.map((person, i) => {
          i === 0 ? person : rows.forEach(row => {
            row[0] === person[0] && row[row.length - 1] === '-3' ? [row, person[1]] : null
          })
        })
      })

      console.log(o)
    })
    .catch(err => rej(err))
//dataset would be Array One and rows would be Array Two
```

This returns `undefined`

I have a feeling I'm either trying to get too complicated/clever with it, or I'm totally out of bounds on this method.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're happy to help with code that isn't working

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Updated to show my current approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out I was definitely trying to be more complicated than I needed to be. I just needed some simple maps and a filter.

```js
let arr1 = [
 ['john', 1, 2, 3, 4, '5'],
 ['jane', 1, 2, 3, 4, '5'],
 ['jane', 1, 2, 3, 4, '-3'],
 ['joe', 1, 2, 3, 4, '-3']
]

let arr2 = [
 ['number', ['jane', 1]]
]

const fx = data => {
 return data.map(s => {
  return s.map((t, u) => {
   return u === 0
    ? t
    : [arr1.filter(v => v[0] === t[0] && v.indexOf('-3') >= 0)[0], t[1]]
  })
 })
}

console.log(fx(arr2))
```